# Swappiness change results in problems

Tags: 14.04, swap

A couple days ago I changed the swappiness of the kernel from 60 to 30.

I am having problems. On boot, I am seeing errors (in windows only; Unity and X.org still work fine as far as I know) that say that programs have crashed and to report it, and that a "System problem detected" or something similar, or "Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error".

How do I fix this without having to bring my swappiness up to 60, or can I not solve it in another way? Are these problems bugs or is this what happens when you change swappiness?

Comment: Come on people. This is very important and I'm sure many others are having this problem.

Comment: P.S. I changed my swappiness from 60 to 30.

Comment: It's time for a bounty.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Right now, there is little to work with. It is unclear if the errors are related to swap at all. Which applications crashed, how often do they crash, etc.

Comment: The program that usually crashes is zeitgeist-daemon and it crashes nearly every system startup.

Comment: Why can't it be brought back up to 60?

Comment: Does changing swappiness back to 60 remove the problem?

Comment: It sounds more like a zeitgeist bug to me, that could be unrelated to swap. Please provide more info in your question. The log info from `zeitgeist-daemon --log-level=DEBUG` could be interesting, I'm not exactly sure where the ends up, though. Try `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: Why do you think that the swappiness change is related to the problem? It would be strange for changing swappiness to have an effect other than making your system slightly less reactive. Who are the “many people” that this affects? Messages like "System problem detected" are very generic and can have many different causes. Also, what do you mean by “in windows only” — do you mean only in certain programs? Which ones, and how does this reconcile with "Ubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error" (where's that message from anyway)?

Comment: The reason you aren't getting answers is likely because you have provided very little information (you don't even say where the errors are from; are they copy-pasted at least?), and the information that you supply most prominently is likely irrelevant (the swappiness thing). At the very least, change swappiness back to confirm or infirm whether that's the cause.

Comment: Changing swappiness to 60 does fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will take a guess here, taking the OP's remark as granted that the problem can be reverted by changing `swappiness` back to 60.

The Linux kernel will usually overcommit memory availability. If you reduce `swappiness`, you tell it to use the swap space to a lesser extent for RAM which programs need, as balanced against using the RAM for cached file data. If you set `swappiness` to 0, you request that your swap space should not be used at all.

However, even with a `swappiness` of 0, the Linux kernel will change its behaviour once it estimates that it is close to an "out of memory" condition. Before that, it will simply not cache any file data in RAM. But once it figures that it is running out of memory, it will change its strategy and use any available swap area despite the `swappiness` setting (unless certain special conditions apply).

You report that you see this phenomenon during boot. This is a situation where many processes are started in parallel, start to analyse their config, allocate memory on demand, etc.

While changing `swappiness` from `60` tp `30` does not change the total space for execution, maybe it does change the amount of memory which the kernel reports to be available. Or it could change the behaviour regarding the point in time when the OOM condition is determined.

So if you happen to have only just about enough RAM and swap for everything that is going to start, the effect you see might be an unfortunate behaviour when the kernel transitions from overreporting to actually providing memeory, or when it starts to believe that an out of memory condition is becoming more likely. The [code in `vmscan.c`](http://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/mm/vmscan.c.html) for example (responsible for freeing memory in RAM) will abruptly change its behaviour depending on such drastic change of conditions.

Comment: This time I will change my swappiness to ten and hope nothing goes wrong. If something does go wrong, I will just file a bug report on it.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste And are you actually short on RAM? Then maybe 10 will not work well, either.

Comment: Nope. 10 works perfectly. I have 4 GB.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste Glad to hear. Then I guess 30 just led to an unfortunate combination of behaviours in your case.